# boost is_invocable_v and is_invocable::value returning different results

Tags: c++, boost

Since I had to write some C++14 compatible code where I still wanted to make use of `std::is_invocable` in a template I tried to use `boost::callable_traits::is_invocable`. However while `boost::callable_traits::is_invocable` returned similar results, `boost::callable_traits::is_invocable_v` did not.

Here is a simple example of the behaviour:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/callable_traits.hpp>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

int test(int){
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "boost::callable_traits::is_invocable_v: "
        << boost::callable_traits::is_invocable_v<decltype(test), int> << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "boost::callable_traits::is_invocable: "
        << boost::callable_traits::is_invocable<decltype(test), int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "std::is_invocable_v: "
        << std::is_invocable_v<decltype(test), int> << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "std::is_invocable: "
        << std::is_invocable<decltype(test), int>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Boost version: 1_72
boost::callable_traits::is_invocable_v: 0
boost::callable_traits::is_invocable: 1
std::is_invocable_v: 1
std::is_invocable: 1
```

I uploaded the code to [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1WuY15kfbzhYPbz9) aswell.

Whats the reason for this surprising behaviour?

Comment: I don't know whether this is important, but which Boost version?

Comment: Ah your right. It is boost version 1.72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Boost bug to me. `is_invocable` and `is_invocable_v` have different implementations (taken from Boost 1.69, comment is mine):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct is_invocable : detail::is_invocable_impl<T, Args...>::type {
    using type = typename detail::is_invocable_impl<T, Args...>::type;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_invocable_v =
    detail::is_invocable_impl<detail::traits<T>, Args...>::type::value;

//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Why?
```

I guess `detail::traits<T>` should be just `T`. In your particular example, `detail::traits<T>` is `detail::function<int(int)>`. Its invocability has nothing to do with invocability of `test`.

Comment: Yes thats what confused me aswell, since I expected is_invocable_v to simply use is_invocable.

Comment: @maxbachmann, opened an [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/callable_traits/issues/184).

Comment: This is an ugly bug, sorry. Will be fixed in Boost 1.74.